# where clause after limiting results

Tags: mysql, count, where

I have a question about getting results after limiting the rows.

I don't have much experience with MySQL, but I'm trying to get results from a database where I need to do the where clause after limiting the results.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(measurement) as 'measurement errors'
FROM measurelog
WHERE (measurement < (baseline - tolerance))
ORDER BY Id DESC
LIMIT 100
```

I only need the measurement values of the last 100 rows, so I expect to get about 5~10 results, but now the programm counts untill it has found 100 faulty measurements.

I've tried to switch the where clause to the bottom, but then I get an syntax error from the MySQL client.

Is there something I'm missing?
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: *I only need the measurement values of the last 100 rows* You MUST use subquery for isolate this 100 records, and then perform counting in outer query. But your query do not contain GROUP BY clause at all - so you always will get only one output record, one count value (and always 100 if you'll isolate 100 records).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Akina for the tip, got it working using the following query

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(measurement) as 'Measurement Errors'
     FROM ( 
        SELECT *
        FROM measurelog
        ORDER BY Id DESC
        LIMIT 100
        ) sub
    WHERE (measurement < (baseline - tolerance))
```

which now returned 7 results